# Posting php variables to page with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to set a confirmation box to delete a message using javascript/jquery on a php page. The variables are being set correctly in the javascript function, but now I can't get the function to properly post to the page.

I have the following included in the head

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Now for the code.

```
//displays a list of messages w/ button to delete 
if(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['msg'] == "msgDetail")){
            $msg->messageDetail($msgID);
            $action = "delete";
            $msgID = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['msgID']);

            //display a delete button that sends variables to javascript function
            echo '<td>'.'<input type="button" value="Delete Message" name = "deleteMessage" onclick="deleteMessage(\'' . $msgID .'\', \'' .$action. '\',\'' .$userid. '\')" />'.'</td>';
        }
        ?>

        //javascript function for confirmation to delete message
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function deleteMessage(msgID, action, userid){
            //document.write(msgID + action + userid) values are correctly showing up here when uncommented
                if (!confirm("Are you sure?"))
                    return false;
                $.post('messages.php',"msgID=" + msgID + "&action=" + action + "&user=" + userid, function(response) {
                    //window.location.reload()
                });
        }
        </script>
    <?

      //check to see if the values have been posted
    if($_POST['action']) == "delete"){
        echo "success!";
             ....more code
    }
```

As you can see, I'm trying to post the variables to messages.php but when I check if even one is posted, nothing happens.

Comment: FYI: `mysql_real_escape_string` is for input, no point calling it on output, you'll need to call it again within messages.php before you insert anyway.

Comment: As for your problem, your code looks ok, can you check your messages.php page, the problem is likely there.

Comment: What should I be looking for? I bumped my if statement to check for POSTED values to the very top. The only thing before it is an include statement for a couple pages and a session variable.

Comment: ah I see the code above is `messages.php`? if so you won't see the `success!` echo unless you're looking in the response from your ajax call with something like firebug.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming) Try reading this, might clear up some things for you.

Comment: I'm using this exact same script on another portion of my site which is why I'm confused that it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at just the javascript, `deleteMessage()` could be written as follows to avoid messy string handling and to give you better feedback while debugging :

```
function deleteMessage(msgID, userid) {
    if (!confirm("Are you sure?")) { return false; }
    var data = {
        'action': 'delete',
        'msgID': msgID,
        'user': userid
    };
    $.ajax({
        url:'messages.php',
        data: data,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);//debug message
            //window.location.reload()
        },
        error: function((jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert((typeof errorThrown == 'string') ? errorThrown : textStatus);//debug message
        }
    });
}
```

You may choose to switch back to `$.post()` when everything is debugged.

You'll see that `'action': 'delete'` is hard coded. It's a minor point but there's no point passing 'delete' through to `deleteMessage` because a function so named isn't going to do anything else. A corresponding change needs to be made where the `<td><input...onclick="..."/></td>` HTML is built.